# Registering an Object that has a string array as a parameter using Castle Windsor Fluent Registration API

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

I have a hopefully simple question...

I am trying to change over from the XML registration to the Fluent Registration API, but am having one problem with registering objects that require an array as a constructor parameter.

For example

```
  <component id="Example" lifestyle="transient"
    service="Test, Example.Test"
    type="Test, Example.Test">
    <parameters>
      <C>
        <array>
          <item>Value One</item>
          <item>Value Two</item>
        </array>
      </C>
    </parameters>
  </component>
```

How would I go about registering this with the fluent api?

```
//the constructor for test is Test(string[] C){}

_container.Register(Component.For<Test>().ImplementedBy<Test>().Parameters(
                        Parameter
                        .ForKey("C")
                        .Eq(new string[]{"Value one","Value two"})
                        ));
```

Comment: BTW if service == type you don't need ImplementedBy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC it's something like this:

```
_container.Register(Component.For<Test>().ImplementedBy<Test>().DependsOn(
                    Property
                    .ForKey("C")
                    .Eq(new string[]{"Value one","Value two"})
                    ));
```

See the [fluent registration wiki](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API#FluentRegistrationAPI-Supplyinginlinedependencies) for more information.

Comment: Perfect!  I just realised that they recently updated the Fluent API documentation page...  Thanks!

Comment: lol, recently means today :) And I'm glad it has already come in handy.